# Only connect to database when necessary

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons

I'm using Pylons + Python and am trying to figure how how to connect to our central database server only when necessary.

I created a class called Central() which I would like to instantiate whenever a connection to the central database server is necessary, e.g.:

```
class Central():

def __init__(self):

    engine = engine_from_config(config, 'sqlalchemy.central.')     
    central_db = create_engine(engine)

    print central_db
```

However this doesn't work when I call:

```
c = DBConnect.Central()
```

What is the proper code for doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: By "doesn't work" do you mean that you left off the `self.` that would make the various values part of the object?  Can you provide any error message or traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't tell what's the layout of your code, I can only assume that you've got `engine` and `central_db` defined somewhere in the global context. Is that correct? If so you could try something like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    global engine
    global central_db
    engine = engine_from_config(config, 'sqlalchemy.central.')     
    central_db = create_engine(engine)
```

It will reference global `engine` and `central_db` objects instead of local ones (as ***Wim*** described)

Answer (score 0):

Can you define "doesn't work"?

If you want to use `central_db` and `engine` later, you need to store them in the object (use `self.central_db`, `self.engine`, you can later access them as `c.central_db` and `c.engine`). Now they're just local variables which are destroyed once your constructor is finished.

Comment: I get bombarded with all sorts of errors.  When I implement what you suggest, I'm thrown a:

NameError: global name 'engine' is not defined

Comment: If I change everything to self. I get:

AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'get_dialect'